# Div drop only accept 1 draggable item Js Vanilla

Tags: javascript, drag, drop

I'm trying to make a drag an drop,  until now, it's okay.

But, I would like to put only 1 item per "drop" div, and I have no idea how to do it.

I would like to know, what should i put in my Js Code, so that the div only accepts on item and reject the other item automatically once it's "full".

Thank you in advance !

```js
function start(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.getAttribute("id"));
}

function over(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e) {
  ob = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  e.currentTarget.appendChild(document.getElementById(ob));
}
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to stop adding items after reaching a certain count? If yes, you can use `e.currentTarget.childElementCount == x` condition to stop appending children in `div`.

Comment: Yes that's it I would like to limit the number of elements per div (1 max)